# Juniper Netscreen Reset to factory defaults. Does license remain in tact?

Tags: juniper

I bought an SSG-5 with the extended license off of ebay. I was messing with the config, and now I want to reset it in order to start fresh. If I do this, will I loose my license information or will it remain on the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Based on the SSG5's own manual](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/hardware/netscreen-systems/netscreen-systems54/HW_SSG5_540.pdf) (check out page 40), reseting the device does not make any mention of deleting the license.

[Based on Juniper's own documentation](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB3466), deleting a license file is only done through a command plus a reset, not merely a reset. [Another reference](http://www.juniper.fr/techpubs/en_US/junos11.2/topics/task/operational/junos-licenses-deleting.html).

Knowing your ScreenOS version might help too, but signs point to the strong liklihood that your license will remain on the device after a reset.

Comment: I can verify that the license remained when I reset the device.

Comment: @Climber104 Excellent! Thanks for updating the thread.